# My JavaScript pop up modal only works on the first item?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I want a pop up modal to appear once a user clicks on a div, i've got a script that works but it will only work on the first div rather than all of them. I've linked the code below. Where do you think i'm going wrong?

```
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div class="job-wrap">
  <button id="myBtn">
    <div class="job-box">
      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="position-type">Part Time</p>
        <p class="job-role">Graphic Designer</p>
        <p class="company-name">Deans School Supply</p>
      </div>
      <div class="time-box">
        <p>9 Days ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p class="job-type">Full Time</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: i dont see jquery being used.. am i wrong or just your tag misleading?

Comment: ps. `document.getElementById('myModal')` will only match the first item with that id and ignore the rest. if you want life easier, use jquery with class selector..

Comment: @BagusTesa Sorry I added the jquery tag by mistake. :/

Comment: I don't see any use of jQuery... But no use of BootStrap either. And that, is something OP should look. There are some data attributes existing in Bootstrap to toggle modals...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `id` attribute should be unique on the page, don't multiply it! (and i'm assuming thats what you are doing, since you want multiple buttons to open modal). Secondly, you are matching only the first found `id` with the `document.getElementById` function. You should use the class attribute and the `document.getElementsByClassName` function instead.

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div class="job-wrap">
  <button class="myBtn">
    <div class="job-box">
      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="position-type">Part Time</p>
        <p class="job-role">Graphic Designer</p>
        <p class="company-name">Deans School Supply</p>
      </div>
      <div class="time-box">
        <p>9 Days ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p class="job-type">Full Time</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.etElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```